# Eclipse CodeMix Angular Plugin Permissions Problem on Windows

Tags: angular, eclipse

I'm running Eclipse 2019-12 on Windows 7 Professional and am looking to get into Angular.  I wanted to try out the CodeMix Angular plugin for Eclipse (listed on marketplace as Angular IDE CI 2020.7.22).  However, when I start it up, I was getting permissions errors.  The problem seems related to how I run as a user but some part of the plugin needs additional administrative privileges.  Here is what I've done so far:

Before taking any corrective actions, I was getting an error saying that ECLIPSE_HOME was not defined.  This was a misleading error, as the problem was actually related to permissions.  I note this as the error changed after making a few modifications as noted below:

I've gone into Window->Preferences->CodeMix->Miscellaneous->Storage and set the CodeMix Extensions location to a location in a folder my user has full priviledges of.  This got me part of the way there.

I've updated the permissions on the workspace folder I'm trying to use to ensure every user has full control over it.

I've even updated the eclipse install folder to give users full permissions over it (though I don't think this had any impact).

There seems to be a missing piece of the permissions puzzle still, as it seems to run okay if I run as administrator.  But it is unlikely that I will be able to run as administrator in a work setting, so I would like to solve getting it to run as a user.

At this point, I'm still getting the following error in the log when trying to run as a user:

```
!ENTRY com.genuitec.eclipse.code.ui 4 0 2021-04-04 17:34:33.487
!MESSAGE Invalid thread state detected on read.
!STACK 0
com.genuitec.eclipse.code.common.GenuitecCoreRTException: Invalid thread state detected on read.
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.D.B(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.D.J(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.D.K(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.C.doIsTrialValid(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.C.A(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.C.getLicenseStatus(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.C.getLicenseStatus(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.ViperCore.getLicenseStatus(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.vU.B(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.vU.AS__111164asdfae2342fa(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.ui.languages.LanguagesService.<init>(LanguagesService.java:194)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.ui.languages.LanguagesService.<clinit>(LanguagesService.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.EditorRegistry.initializeFromStorage(EditorRegistry.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.EditorRegistry.<init>(EditorRegistry.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$15.compute(WorkbenchPlugin.java:1365)
```

And also:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2021-04-04 17:34:36.233
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Check license status".
!STACK 0
com.genuitec.eclipse.code.common.GenuitecCoreRTException: Invalid thread state detected on read.
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.D.B(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.D.J(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.D.K(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.C.doIsTrialValid(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.C.A(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.C.getLicenseStatus(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.C.getLicenseStatus(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.ViperCore.getLicenseStatus(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.vU.B(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.vU.AS__111164asdfae2342fa(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.ui.languages.LanguagesService$1.run(LanguagesService.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Anyone have any thoughts on what else may need to be changed to get the Eclipse Angular plugin to work on Windows running as a User?

Comment: Scott, this looks like an issue that was resolved quite some time ago with CodeMix / Angular IDE. It does look like an inability to access the location in which Eclipse is installed, as well as all the folders within - have those folders had their access corrected as well? Are you using a regular "unzip style" install of Eclipse or an Oomph based centralized install? Another option is using our all-in-one installer which will lay down a dedicated install. For better support, do post on our forums: https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topics/codemix/getting-help/

Comment: The Eclipse Angular plugin is [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper). You have a plugin for Eclipse not from an Eclipse project.